# On Date base record return

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table structure like this

```
 vehid   TimeFirst      TimeLast       Inside

  1      26/06/2014     null              0        
  2      26/06/2014     26/06/2014        1 
  2      26/06/2014     null              0
  3      26/06/2014     26/06/2014        1
```

I want to return only those record on the base of veh enter and left on same day and only pick left record of those vehls.Inside 0 mean veh left and 1 mean enter.expect output below

```
    vehid   TimeFirst      TimeLast       Inside

     2      26/06/2014       null          0
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What if the same vehicle leaves twice and enters once in the same day? Which leave should show up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT S.* FROM Table1 T JOIN Table1 S ON
       T.TimeFirst = T.TimeLast AND 
       T.Inside = 1 AND 
       T.TimeLast = S.TimeFirst
WHERE S.Inside = 0 AND S.Vehid = T.Vehid
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb446/6)**

Output would be:

---

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| VEHID   | TIMEFIRST     | TIMELAST      | INSIDE      |
+---------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2       | 2014-06-26    | (null)        | 0           |
+---------+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: sorry Timelast is null...i update the question plz check

Answer (score 0):

Here, you might need to exclude the time from the Datetime :

```
select * from tableName a
    where          
    convert(date, timeFirst) in ( select convert(date, timeLast) from tableName where id = a.id) 
    and inside = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Ent.VehID, Ent.TimeFirst, Exit.TimeLast, Exit.Inside
FROM myTable Ent
JOIN myTable Exit
ON Ent.TimeFirst = Exit.TimeFirst
AND Ent.VehID = Exit.VehID 
AND Ent.Inside = 1 AND Exit.Inside = 0
```

If there are multiple entrance and exits for same day for same vehicle you will get duplicate records and you would need to use `Distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT  P2.*
FROM    Parking P1 INNER JOIN
        Parking P2 ON P2.VehID = P1.VehID AND 
                      P2.TimeFirst = P1.TimeLast
WHERE   P1.Inside = 1 AND P2.Inside = 0
```

Comment: Hm, I assume you either mean to select  P1.* or P2.*.